# Memory Partitioning in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, memory-management, amazon-ec2, partitioning

I need to launch an EC2 of instance type **r3.4xlarge** from a snapshot of a free-tier instance I initially had.

Now, first, I launched it directly, without editing the storage options. I was left with 8GiB `root` volume, 61GiB in `/udev` [ `/dev` ] and another 61GiB in `none` or `/run/shm`.

My question is: WHERE IS MY 122GB MEMORY AND HOW CAN I ACCESS IT?

The things that I have tried:

1. Added volume to the root, increased root size from 8GiB to 15GiB using these [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html). I also ended up with an increased root volume from 8GiB to 117GiB in my second attempt, when I tried to use 118GiB from my 122GiB, and changed the volume size of the root device during **launch** of the instance from the AMI. The **problem** here is that: Only the root volume changes from 8GiB to 117GiB, the `/udev` and `/run/shm` still have a total of 61GiB each.

   `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`

   `udev             61G   12K   61G   1% /dev`

   `tmpfs            13G  328K   13G   1% /run`

   `/dev/xvda1      117G  6.3G  105G   6% /`

   `none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup`

   `none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock`

   `none             61G     0   61G   0% /run/shm`

   `none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user`
2. Tried to Partition the existing system. Using these [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm). When I attempt `sudo pvs` there is no output and the terminal shows me the prompt. When I do `sudo lvs`, I get *No Logical Volumes found.* I then try to do [this](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v5/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23117.htm) before I try to do anything with lvm2. But it's still the same on reboot.

Kindly help me with this issue. I'm stuck at a difficult place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing RAM and Volume storage. An r3.4xlarge has 122GB of RAM. This is available for your applications to use, try:

```
free -m
```

to see more about your RAM.

r3.4xlarge comes with 1 320GB SSD ephemeral storage.

Comment: Where is this 320GB SSD ephemeral storage located? Please forgive my ignorance. Or is it on-demand? As in, as long as I'm paying $xyz/month for r3.4xlarge, I can increase my volumes upto 320GB, for no additional cost?

Comment: dude, r3.4xlerge is not cheap. Please read docs carefully before spending money! http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html